# Show that if $a$ is odd, $r \geq 3$, and $x^2 \equiv a \pmod {2^r}$, then $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $a$ is odd, $r \geq  3$, and $x^2 \equiv a \pmod {2^r}$, then $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.

We have been thinking about this one for a while now, not too sure what to do.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ is odd $\implies x^2 $ is odd $\implies x$  is odd $\implies x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8$

**EDIT**
$x$ is odd $\implies x = 2k+1 \implies x^2 = (2k+1)^2 =4k^2+4k+1 = 4k(k+1)+1=8k'+1\equiv 1\pmod 8$

$k(k+1)$ is the product of consecutive integers, so it is even.

Comment: Could you explain the last implication?

Comment: @SeanC See the edit

Comment: I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The given congruence is equivalent to $$x^2=2^r.n+a$$(for some $n\in \mathbb Z)$
but then since $a$ is odd so is $x^2$. Therefore $x$ is odd as well. Hence $x=2k+1$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$. $$x^2=4k^2+4k+1=4k(k+1)+1=8q+1$$ since $k(k+1)$ is always even. So $$x^2\equiv 1\bmod 8$$

Answer (score 0):

From the congruence relation you have: $2^r \mid x^2 - 1$, since $r\ge 3$ we have: $2 \mid x^2 - a$. Now since a is odd we have that $x$ is also odd. And now it's fairly easy to see that for every odd number $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$